# Center of mass of convex 3-D shape

Tags: real-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

Could you please help me, or give the hint:

Let $T\subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a convex 3-D shape, and let $k$ be the center of mass of this shape.

How to prove that $k\in T$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Intuitively if a region is convex it just means it contains straight lines connecting two points inside it. You can just compare this to the classical definition of centre of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Assume ${\rm vol}(T)>0$. If the centroid $c$ of $T$ is $\notin T$ then there is a separating hyperplane, which we may assume to be the plane $x_3=0$. We then have $c=(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ with $c_3\leq0$, but  all $x\in T$ satisfy  $x_3\geq0$. There is even a small ball $B\subset T$ lying completely above the plane $x_3=0$.

Now the formula for the centroid $c$ says that
$$c_3={{\displaystyle\int_T x_3\>{\rm dvol}(x)}\over{\rm vol}(T)}\quad .$$
Here the right hand side is $>0$ – a contradiction.